# While Loop entire select Tag

Tags: php, html, mysqli, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to while loop an entire select tag to have multiple dropdown menus?
What I am trying to achieve is to have a column full of dropdown menus in a table.

**This is what I have tried so far**

```
<?php
    $DNS_FROM = $DNS."_port-%";
    $select = "SELECT * FROM `uplink_port_mapping` WHERE DNS_From LIKE '$DNS_FROM'";
    $select1 = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
    $select2 = "SELECT DNS_From FROM `uplink_port_mapping` WHERE DNS_From NOT LIKE '$DNS_FROM' AND DNS_To = ''";
    $select3 = mysqli_query($conn, $select2);
    while($uplink_from = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select1)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$uplink_from['DNS_From']."</td>";
        echo "<td>"."<select name = 'uplink_to' multiple='multiple'> 
        <option value = '".$uplink_from['DNS_To']."' selected='selected'>". $uplink_from['DNS_To']."</option>";

        while ($uplink_to = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select3)){
                echo "<option value='".$uplink_to['DNS_From']."'>".$uplink_to['DNS_From']."</option>";
        }

        echo"</select>";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
    }
?>
```

[How it is right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcn0k.png)

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: If you try to put <select> inside another <select>, it will not work. Let us now more details.

Comment: @Gopal Yes I have tried. It does create multiple dropdown menus. However, it only populates the first dropdown only.

Comment: @Deepak Show your code, and we'll gladly help you troubleshoot! But this isn't a one-way street! ;-) A `<select>` can only hold `<option>` and `<optgroup>` tags, you can't have a select within a select tag.

Comment: @Qirel I have posted the code. Also I know that a select tag inside another select tag will not work.

Comment: `echo"</select>";`this shouldn't be inside the while-loop, it should be outside. Also, `<td>` tags isn't valid HTML inside a `<select>`-group either.

Comment: I think you need a dropdown menu which allows multiple select. Use <select name = 'uplink_to' multiple>

Comment: @Qirel tried echo "/select" outside the while loop. Nothing changed. Also if you look carefully, the td tag is outside the select tag.

Comment: @Ashish Doesn't work either.

Comment: Actually you want another drop down <select>?

Comment: @Qirel echo"</select>"; and <td> both are outside inner while loop, and is correct

Comment: @Ashish You are correct, indeed! I missed the closing bracket `}` (should be better intented) ;-)

Comment: the last `echo "<tr>"` should be `echo "</tr>"`!

Comment: and also better add a `<table>` plus a `</table>`

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the correction. However it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @Jeff Its outside the PHP tag that i havent shown

Comment: then what exactly is not working as expected? what is the out put? are there errors shown?

Comment: I have got all the dropdown menus, however the results are only being generated for the first drop down and not all the others. It's most likely to do something with the second while loop

Comment: yes, you'd have to reset the result of mysqli_fetch_assoc. But better solution would be to store those into an array first, then loop through that array.

Comment: eighter add `mysql_data_seek($result, 0);` before the inner while loop

Comment: @Jeff I see what you mean. So would I be then using a foreach loop or should i stick with the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the second while loop only working once is, that `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` will leave the pointer of the $result recource at it's end. 
So when you try to loop the second time, `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` will not return anything (cause it's at the end of the $result recource.

Two possibilites:

Reset the pointer to the beginning:

```
<?php 
....
while($uplink_from = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select1)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$uplink_from['DNS_From']."</td>";
    echo "<td>"."<select name = 'uplink_to' multiple='multiple'> 
    <option value = '".$uplink_from['DNS_To']."' selected='selected'>". $uplink_from['DNS_To']."</option>";

    // here's the change:
    mysql_data_seek($select3, 0);

    while ($uplink_to = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select3)){
            echo "<option value='".$uplink_to['DNS_From']."'>".$uplink_to['DNS_From']."</option>";
    }

    echo"</select>";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
}
.... 
?>
```

Or - which I think is the better solution - store that data into an array first, and then walk through that array:

```
<?php
...
$select2 = "SELECT DNS_From FROM `uplink_port_mapping` WHERE DNS_From NOT LIKE '$DNS_FROM' AND DNS_To = ''";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $select2);
$dns_from = Array();
while ($uplink_to = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select3)){
    $dns_from[] = $uplink_to;
}

....
// inside your first while loop:
foreach($dns_from as $dns) {
   echo "<option value='".$dns['DNS_From']."'>".$dns['DNS_From']."</option>";
}
....
// note that I left out a bunch of your code, that doesn't change.
?>
```

Comment: I will stick with the first solution. Thanks though :)

Comment: The first solution is a quick fix, but leaves you with not well structured code. The more you seperate data fetching from data showing the better. Also get used to more meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple select dropdown basic examples

```
$array = [
'Apple' => 1,
'Orange' => 0,
'Banana' => 1,
];
echo '<select multiple>';
foreach ($array as $fruit => $sel) {
    $selected = 0;
    if ($sel == 1) {
        $selected = 'selected';
    }
    echo '<option value="' . $fruit . ' " ' . $selected . '>' . $fruit . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```